# could you help me undrstand the parrallelisme in VHDL?

Tags: concurrency, vhdl, fpga, hdl

I understand that in a process the instructions are executed sequentially and that the value of a signal is not updated until the end of the process, but I can not understand the principle of parallelism? for example in the following code I know that both instructions will be executed in parallel (at the same time) but I do not know if Q will have the new value of Sig2 or the precidente also when we calculate Sig2 do we use the new value of Sig1 or the precidente ?

`Sig1<=a and b;
Sig2<=Sig1 and a;
Q<=Sig2;`

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements
"A concurrent signal assignment statement represents an equivalent process statement that assigns values to signals." 10.2 Wait statements, paragraphs 3&4 "This rule is also used to construct the sensitivity sets of the wait statements in the equivalent process statements for ..., and concurrent signal assignment statements (11.6)." The equivalent processes are sensitive to events on signals evaluated on the right hand side of a signal assignment.  (Concurrent - not parallel doesn't mean continuous, try simulating).

Answer (score 0):

As VHDL uses event driven semantics, nothing actually executes in parallel. It just has the appearance of parallelism. The concurrent assignments you show execute whenever the RHS operands change—there is no implied ordering. If `a` changes from 1 to 0, you cannot depend on which order the first two statements execute. It's possible the 2<sup>nd</sup> assignment executes first, then the 1<sup>st</sup> assignment executes second, followed by the 3<sup>rd</sup> assignment executes third (because `Sig2` has changed) and then the 2<sup>nd</sup> assignment executes again because `Sig1` has changed.

Most tools will try to order the statements to minimize the number of assignment re-executions and may even optimize it as if you wrote:

```
Q <= a and b;
```

and eliminate `Sig1` and `Sig2` from the simulation.

Comment: first of all thank you very much, so the value ((a and b) and a ) will be assigned directly to Q as if the assignment of the values is done sequentially as an ordinary programming language?

Comment: No, not as if sequentially. The order concurrent statements are executed in is not defined by the standard and is implementation dependent, as well as event driven.  dave_59 is mistaken in using a generalization "Most tools will try to order the statements to minimize the number of assignment re-executions and may even optimize ..." No signal assignment is optimized away, while in synthesis intermediary nets can be, they are different domains VHDL the simulation language and an elaborated design hierarchy mapped to hardware.

Comment: @user1155120, I've worked for three different companies that currently produce VHDL simulators, and know this to be true. This is why you need +acc or access switches when you want to dump signals to a waveform. This preserves their existence.

Comment: @Rachid_Tahiri an *ordinary programming language* within a single thread only deals with variable assignments in a sequential order. It matters how you order the writes versus reads to get different state behaviors. The same is true in VHDL procedures. But when you have multiple processes/threads, VHDL requires that you use signals instead of variables to communicate between processes.